# Cross Compilation for Windows on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, windows, compilation, linker

I'm trying to compile c++ code on Linux, to run on Windows, using MinGW-w64, but I don't know how to apply the flags I usually use when compiling for linux. Say for example I use the link flag -lX11 to link on Linux when using g++, how would I use that corresponding flag to compile for Windows using MinGW-w64?
Thanks in advance for the help!!

Comment: As there is no built-in support for X11 on Windows, just remove the flag.

Answer (score 2):

Mingw contains a normal g++ so the compile flags shouldn't differ.
linking X11 won't work propably because it isn't available on windows

Comment: So if I want to compile on linux using something like GLFW, to run on windows, that wouldn't work either?

Comment: take a look at how to compile GLFW for Windows. some (etc. graphic) libraries work have platform dependent code. So there are differences. Please take a look at how to compile them with mingw